# Dell VRTX get ip address of server attached to chassis

Tags: ipv4, dell

I wanted to know if there is any racadm command to get the ip address of the attached server's in a dell VRTX chassis.

`racadm getslotname` will give the Host Name of the server but not the ip address.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd venture to say that for PowerEdge VRTX, you're better off asking on [sf].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slotname is a descriptor set by the chassis manager and *not* retrieved from the installed operating system on your blade server and may not actually match your hostname.

You can get the ip-address for the iDrac management console with racadm `getniccfg -m server-<n>` where `<n>` is the slot number 1-16:

```
 racadm getniccfg -m server-1
```

Normally you would use the chassis management console to configure the iDrac interface for each blade in the chassis, and then log into that iDrac management interface to manage that particular blade server from the remote console. And tehre you can manage the ip-address for that server.

E.G. Slots 1 & 2 are our webservers.

```
racadm -i 1 webserver1
racadm -i 2 webserver2
```

And verify with

```
racadm getslotname -i 1
```

Configure the iDrac interfaces for those so we can manage them with `racadm setnicfg` and `racadm deploy` are somewhat interchangeable in configuring a static network address `-u root -p <password>` (we can only configure the administrator password), `server-<n>` (where `<n>` is the slot number 1-16) and the `-s ip-adress netmask gateway` network settings. :

```
racadm setniccfg -m server-1 192.168.10.101 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1

racadm deploy server-1 -u root -p webserver1_passw0rd -s 192.168.10.101 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1
```

And verify with :

```
racadm getniccfg -m server-1
```

`racadm ifconfig` will display the ip-configuration of the CMC for you.

Comment: yes...that worked. thanks a lot...what command would fetch me the OS of the blade servers? Also is there any command/method to get the actual host ip address(not the iDrac Ip address)

Comment: No, the neither the CMC not the DRAC management console has interaction with the OS as far as I know. From the DRAC you may be able to get the MAC adressess of any onboard NIC's and match them with the MAC table in the switch configuration as a crude work-around.